# gradle multiple jars from multiple folders

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

i have a project layout like

sample/
                   A/
                          src/
                                 main/
                                        java/
                                       A.java
                                  res/
                             A.jpg
               B/
                          src/
                                 main/
                                        java/
                                       B.java
                                  res/
                             B.jpg
                   build.gradle
               settings.gradle

how to create two separate jar files(A.jar/B.jar)

A.jar includes A.java, A.jpg

B.jar includes B.java, B.jpg

Comment: Just create `build.gradle` files in both *A* and *B* folders.

Comment: I know that, but i want to without build.gradle
Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/28290254) you can find a sample project. Basically all configuration is put in *build.gradle* and *settings.gradle* files:

**build.gradle**

```
subprojects {
   apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include 'A', 'B'
```